# Rails Web service with authentication??? User logged in ??

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-authentication

Any idea how I would go about have a rails REST web service where a user can only get, put, post, delete only their own data ? I am using Devise as my user authentication gem, but I am not sure if this handles things in a RESTful manner.

How would I assure that the user is 'logged in' and can change their data? Do I have to pass some kind of token around in every request??

Answer (score 3):

Devise will only provide you with authentication. This meaning that you have some level of certainty that the user is identified and is who he/she says he/she is. Given this information, you can use Rails mechanisms or other Rails gems (i.e., CanCan, Aegis, declarative_authorization) to **authorize** users and define permissions.

A simple method would be to use a `before_filter` on your controller in question, to determine if, for example, a `BlogPost` belongs to the user that is signed in.

Here's a simple example of what I mean:

```
class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_user_allowed, :only => [:edit, :delete, :show]

  # default Rails generated RESTful methods here    

  def is_user_allowed
    if BlogPost.find(params[:id]).try(:user_id) != current_user.id
      redirect_to access_denied_page_path
    end
  end
end
```

The `is_user_allowed` method retrieves the `BlogPost` that is being queried and determines whether the `current_user` is allowed to perform the action by comparing the user IDs. If the inequality is true, then it redirects to our infamous `access_denied_page_path`.

For more information on filters, see this [Edge Guides article](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters).

For more information on Rails gems that can provide you this functionality (and **more**), take a look around on Google and search for `rails authorization`. Furthrmore, here are some Railscasts that should provide some insight:

- [192 - Authorization with CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)
- [188 - Declarative Authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)

Comment: This part is fine when logging in through a web browser where there is session data. If I were to try to do restricted methods through a curl call. This does not handle it, as I'm actually trying to go for a REST API. So there were two ways I saw, which is either using basic http authentication or doing something with an API key to identify a particular user. Both ways seem very weak security wise for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [AuthLogic's](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) single_access_token. It was designed for authenticating REST APIs.